# Proving and disproving statements involving quantifiers

Tags: proof-explanation, quantifiers

The question I am trying to answer is:

> Prove or disprove (that is prove it is false) each of the following statements.
>   R is the set of real numbers.
>
> • ∀x ∈ R, ∃y ∈ R, x + y > 0
>
> • ∃x ∈ R, ∀y ∈ R, x + y > 0
>
> • ∀x ∈ R, ∃y ∈ R, xy > 0
>
> • ∃x ∈ R, ∀y ∈ R, xy > 0
>
> • ∀x ∈ R, ∃y ∈ R, xy ≥ 0
>
> • ∃x ∈ R, ∀y ∈ R, xy ≥ 0

I was able to do the first 4, which I got true, false, false, false, respectively. But I am having difficulties with the last two. I am also finding that when doing these I tend to assume that they are false, even if they are true. Can someone explain the last two as well as any tips when dealing with these types of problems?

Comment: A hint for the last two, if it helps: it's quite easy for a product of two numbers to be ${}\ge0$, especially when one of the two numbers equals $0$.

Comment: My original reasoning for the last two was to set $y=-1/x$ and $x=-1/x$ respectively and then the statements would be false since $-1<0$. But is this reasoning invalid since we can't set $x $ or $y$ to something that includes another variable or was my reasoning wrong for a difference reason?